# A tricky batch of four number sequences

Tags: number-sequence

What are the next few numbers in each of these integer sequences? Each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 20, 21, 22, **??**, **??**, ...
>
> 50, 49, 48, 46, 45, 44, 43, 38, ..., 25, 24, 23, **??**, **??**, ...
>
> 11, 12, 20, 30, 80, 90, 10000, **????**
>
> ... 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 40, 46, 60, 61, **??**, **??**, ...

Comment: Hint: Although all of these are number sequences, none of them have anything to do with the actual numerical properties of the numbers themselves whatsoever.

Comment: ,..., means that all numbers in the interval are included?

Comment: No, it means that the numbers in the sequence between 38 and 25 were omitted, and you need to find the numbers that come after 23.

Comment: Any hint for the 2nd sequence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Partial answer**

1)

> **23,25**

Ordinal numbers that aren't made juxtaposing the cardinal and "-th" suffix.
*Credit of this answer to Xyuzhg*

3)

> **Googol**

Numbers that when written have exactly 6 letters. 10000=myriad.

4)

> **64, 80**

Nonnegative integers that when written out in full in English have no repeated letter.

Comment: Your answer for sequence 4 is correct.

Comment: @JoeZ. I added a solution for sequence 3. If wrong i'll delete it

Comment: The rule is correct, but you haven't given me the next number.

Comment: Googol is too big or ok?

Comment: Googol is the correct answer. Good job.

Answer (score 6):

Sequence 1:

> 23, 25 (twenty-third, twenty-fifth)

Reason:

> Numbers that when written in the chronological ordinal series (first, second, third, etc.) are **not** the number appended with "th". ("Eighth" is "eight" + "h".)

Comment: Our solutions for 1 agree everywhere.. but yours is simpler.

Comment: Funny - 0 would be accepted by yours, but not mine. I suppose there are linguistic connections to be made here?

Comment: Well, it's not surprising that 'th' isn't added in bare to a number ending in 't' or 'y'; "two" is 1 of 2 numbers ending in 'o' and by coincidence it becomes "second"; and I guess that the disappearing 'e' makes some sense. Somehow 'dth', 'nth', 'rth', 'xth' are all natural and easy to pronounce. The other number ending in 'o', "zero", happens to not become something special and so gets 'oth', which is also not a problem to speak.

Comment: @Xyuzhg: I didn't include zero because I started counting from 1.

Answer (score 3):

The second sequence is:

> 21, 20

And the pattern is

> the number of stars on the US flag in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

1) All numbers when written out (googol would be ten duotrigintillion) end in one of these letters: denortxy (sorted alphabetically). Take only the even spots of "denortxy" to get "eoty", and now all numbers ending in a letter from "eoty" are in our list.

> ..., 23, 25, 28, 29, ...

Comment: Twenty ends in "y".

Comment: Right, aeiouy then.

Comment: Also, "eight" ends in "t".

Comment: Oh okay nevermind then, I'll think about it.

Comment: "Numbers that end in aeiouy when spelled out normally or that can end in e when spelled out how they sound" works for everything..

Comment: "Eighte"? Also, that rule isn't very elegant.

Comment: Yes, I know it isn't elegant xP. eight->ate.. Though I guess one could argue thirteen -> thirtine

Comment: Yeah, keep looking. You're correct in thinking that it has to do with the English language, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence 2:

> The sequence repeats its interval at every 25
> 50, 49, 48, 46, 45, 44, 43, 38 
> 25, 24, 23, **21**, **20**, 19, 18, 13

my closest guess anyways

Comment: There are numbers between 23 and 38 in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> sequence 2
> 29, 34
> Pattern -1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,-5, then repeats -1,-1,+6,+5

Comment: Please hide your answer in spoiler tags.

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: That's okay, it's one now.